# I want to call controller's Default action.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Example : My User will enter `www.xyz.com/Promo/PROMO123`

where "`PROMO123`" is value, which i require.

above code produces error :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

The resource cannot be found.

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

However 
 `www.xyz.com/Promo/Index/PROMO123` will work properly,
but i dont want this.

How can i archive this

```
 www.xyz.com/Promo/PROMO123
```

Comment: no it's not possible...

Comment: Of course it's possible. Never let the lack of knowledge keep you from finding the solution.

Comment: @itd: there must be a difference of understanding here. You *can* call a URL with just the controller name in it, and fallback to a default action (`Index` in the case of the default route), but you absolutely can't "call" a controller in sense of having it do something directly without any action involved at all. Some action on the controller *must* respond to the request.

Comment: @Aniket: FYI, please only include version number tags for your question if it's directly related to that version of the thing. For example, a feature that only exists in MVC4. If your question is generic and not dependent on the version of the framework, as this one is, just add the main tag only. Also, if a version is applicable, only include that one version you're working with. You're not using both MVC3 and MVC4

Comment: Yes, that is true. If you take the question literally, it is not possible. Somehow I had default actions in my mind when writing my comment, my mistake :P

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Such as

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //Don't forget to add this before default one.
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PromoRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{myString}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Promo", action = "Index", myString = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your route for Promo controller is added before default route. I have posted complete class.

Comment: Try to change 

url: "{controller}/{myString}".

to 

url: "Promo/{myString}"

This way the application will find an exact match. I don't know why the above solution didn't work for you, but if you add the controller name directly to the url, it will use that route. The route still has to be added before the default one though

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route pattern for this.

If you want this to work application wide, then you will need to change the default route. But I would suggest simply adding a specific route for this controller, in addition to the default route, because you probably don't want to override the default MVC routing for the whole app or you will lose the ability to use multiple actions per controller.

See your RouteConfig, try this route (MVC pre-5):

```
 routes.MapRoute("myRoute", "PromoRoute/{id}",
                     new {controller="PromoRoute", action = "Index"});
```

With MVC5 you can add this directly to your action assuming you've enabled attribute routes:

```
 [Route("PromoRoute/{id}")]
 public ActionResult Index(string id) {

 }
```